# Convert Luojia1-01 DN values to radiance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, satellite

I am trying to convert Luojia's DN values to radiance following the equation in the attached image.
[image: equation to convert DN to radiance]

I am using the `Raster Calculator` in ArcMap for this conversion and the command I am typing is `image^(3/2)*10^(-10)` but the resulting image is a binary raster with 0 and 1 values.
[image: dn_to_rad_result]
I tried other things as well, like inserting brackets in the equation etc but the result is the same. Why that output? From [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z2rM9xPeplrhsxkUWaYEK1jNr8RsdRqH?usp=sharing) you can download the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the same formula using `QGIS` the resulting raster is a continuous raster which has a range of pixel values 0-0.08. I'm not sure if `ArcMap` creates a binary raster because it can't capture this small difference.